# Can I just assign members to Lists on Trello on not the entire board? If not, is Trello going to make this possible?

Tags: trello

I need to assign people to individual lists and not the entire board so it is all they see. Is there a way to do this? If not, can I have a list from one board feed into another board automatically?

Answer (score 2):

You can assign people to individual cards, and you can control access to individual boards, but, to keep the product simple and broadly useful, it's not planned (currently) to have list-based permissions.