# Can I automatically assign all new cards in a list to myself?

Tags: trello, trello-cards

This question is similar to, but not quite the same as, the following two questions that have been asked before:

- [Can I just assign members to Lists on Trello on not the entire board? If not, is Trello going to make this possible?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/29657/156027)
- [Can users be subscribed to a list rather than a card](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/31136/156027)

In one of my projects at work, we have our server set up so that any exceptions caused by process Foo get emailed to our Trello board, where they show up in a list titled "Foo exceptions". It's my job to look at those exceptions and either turn them into new bug reports, further data on already-known bug reports, or sometimes new Trello cards representing a new feature we need to add.

I've subscribed to the "Foo exceptions" list so I get notified when a new card shows up, which simplifies my job considerably. (Thanks for adding that feature, Trello team!) But currently, every time a new card shows up in that list I have to assign myself to that card by hand. Is there a way of saying "In addition to being notified every time a new card shows up in that list, I want to be automatically assigned to any new cards that show up in this list"?

By "assigned to a card", I mean having my picture show up on the card: the same process as editing the card, clicking on the Members button, and adding myself.

Answer (score 2):

**[Butler for Trello](https://butlerfortrello.com/dashboard.html)** will do the job for you if you're okay connecting a third-party utility to your Trello account.

The service is offered on a freemium model. You get up to 250 operations a week at the present time at no cost. You pay for more operations per week and additional features.

Once you've authorized Butler to connect with your Trello account, you'll need to select a board to work with, and then set up a recipe like this.

[image: Automatically Join Card in Trello List]

**Caveats**

- On the free and silver plan, the Butler bot is added as a member of your board (with all the privileges of a board member).
- A new list called `Butler` will be added to your board. You can archive this list if you don't need it.

Comment: This answer is out of date. Butler is now part of Trello. See: https://blog.trello.com/50-million-celebration

Answer (score 1):

> we have our server set up so that any exceptions caused by process Foo
>   get emailed to our Trello board,

If you have access to the formatting of those emails, it can be done:

> In the subject, add @username. Members can also be added by putting @username in the body of the email on its own line. If you send an email to Trello and include other Trello users' email addresses as "to" or "CC" addresses, Trello will add them as members of the card as well.

(Quoted from http://help.trello.com/article/809-creating-cards-by-email)